Interating with for_each, need a modified subnet list for each iteration
I have a for_each loop in which I pass a subnet list to a module for creating AWS ASGs.
I'd like the subnet list to be different for each iteration in order to assure that each ASG runs on different subnets.
More specifically, assume I have the following:
locals {
  subnet_list = ["1a", "1b", "1c"]
  instances = {
    iA = {
        disk = "50GB"
    },
    iB = {
        type = "t2.medium"
    },
    iC = {
    },
    iD = {
        disk = "10GB"
    }
  }
}

module my-module {
  for_each = local.instances
  subnets = <terraform-expression>
}

What is the terraform-expression that would allow me to supply different slices of subnet_list to the module, e.g.



Iteration
subnetsAW




1
["1a", "1b", "1c"]


2
["1b", "1c", "1a"]


3
["1c", "1a", "1b"]


4
["1a", "1b", "1c"]



I can get this to work with count = because then I have an iteration count to pass to any slicing expression, but I prefer for_each to allow for easier resource replacement.

for_each takes a (logical) unordered set, so first you have to decide how to assign an index to each instance to slice the subnets list with. The simplest way which avoids assigning indices manually is to sort the instance keys (iA, iB and so on) and use the order of the key in the sorted list as the index, something like this:
locals {
  instance_keys = sort(keys(local.instances))
}
module "my_module" {
  for_each = zipmap(local.instance_keys, range(length(local.instance_keys)))
  # instance name is each.key
  # instance data is local.instances[each.key]
  # instance index is each.value, use to slice subnet list
}

However, with this approach adding a new instance iA1 will cause the subnet assignments of iB and all subsequent instances to change. If this is undesirable, hash the instance name and use that to index subnet slices:
locals {
  instance_index = [for k in keys(local.instances):
    # note: using md5 for hashing, not for security
    parseint(substr(md5(k),0,8),16) % length(local.subnets) # or something
  ]
}
module "my_module" {
  for_each = zipmap(keys(local.instances), instance_index)
  # instance name is each.key
  # instance data is local.instances[each.key]
  # instance index is each.value, use to slice subnet list
}

This doesn't guarantee uniqueness of subnet assignments, but I don't think any approach immune to the iA1 problem can do that.

Slightly modified for my purposes but a perfect solution, thanks for the answer

You're welcome. If so please mark the answer as accepted!
